# Bazaar Trader combo and Void Snare - Ownership vs. Control

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I use [Bazaar Trader](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bazaar%20Trader) and [Act of Treason](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Act%20of%20Treason) to gain control of a creature my opponent controls.

If my opponent uses a card such as [Void Snare](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Void%20Snare) on that creature, does the card go to my hand or my opponents hand?

Comment: I'm confused, why is Bazaar Trader in this?  Isn't your question about Act of Treason?  Bazaar Trader gives your opponent control of one of your creatures.

Comment: @John by using Bazaar Trader, I can permanently gain control ( but not ownership ) of the opponents creature that I temporarily borrowed with Act of Treason.  Bazaar Trader either gives my opponent a card or asserts ownership over one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you note in your title, there is a difference between ownership and control.

> 110.2. A permanent's owner is the same as the owner of the card that represents it (unless it's a token; see rule 110.5a). A permanent's controller is, by default, the player under whose control it entered the battlefield. Every permanent has a controller.
>   110.5a A token is both owned and controlled by the player under whose control it entered the battlefield.

So clearly, we know the owner of the card, and where it goes as a result of void snare.

But let's say, for some reason, it said *controller's hand* instead of *owner's hand*. That's already covered: cards only ever go to their *owner's* hand.

> 400.3. If an object would go to any library, graveyard, or hand other than its owner’s, it goes to its owner’s corresponding zone.

As for who the owner is, well that's also defined for us:

> 108.3. The owner of a card in the game is the player who started the game with it in his or her deck. If a card is brought into the game from outside the game rather than starting in a player's deck, its owner is the player who brought it into the game. If a card starts the game in the command zone, its owner is the player who put it into the command zone to start the game. **Legal ownership** of a card in the game is irrelevant to the game rules except for the rules for ante.

Comment: this is disappointing for me and great news for my friend.  thank you!

Comment: @JacobRaccuia As 400.3 indicates, the game never places your property in a position where it could be confused for someone else's property. Far too easy to accidentally leave your card in someone else's deck that way (or for someone to dispute that it was yours in the first place).

Comment: That's been the idea all along, I would imagine. And these days so many people are using sleeves, that would be... a little strange.

Comment: "A permanent's owner is the same as the owner of the card that represents it." - But do the rules define who is the owner of the card? Normally this would be the person who is actually the literal owner (outside of MTG rules) of the card... but if you're playing with a friend's deck or something, then I assume you're the owner of all cards in the deck during the game. Do the rules define this?

Comment: Yes, that is defined. I edited that in just now.

Answer (score -4):

More to the point, Act of Treason by itself only lasts for one turn. Void Snare is a sorcery speed card, which means it can only be played on the turn of the active player. By the time your opponent could play void snare, it'd be of no effect.

If you want to circumvent all of these effects, look into a Conjurers Closet or Momentary Blink.

Comment: Yes, Act of Treason only lasts for one turn. That's why he also uses Bazaar Trader: to permanently give himself control of the creature once he temporarily has control of it, by targeting himself. This comment doesn't actually answer the question in any way, it just suggests using a combo like the one in the question to achieve the goal described in the premise of the question.

Comment: @Travis, Please don't leave comments as answers.